# Prediction with LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm

I want to predict prices using LSTM, but the model at the end of time period lost the track and can not follow the trend.
I do not know what the problem could be, does anybody have a solution?

Different parts of my code can be seen below:

---

```
X_train = []
y_train = []

n_future = 8   # Number of hours we want top predict into the future
n_past = 144    # Number of past hours we want to use to predict the future

for i in range(n_past, len(training_set_scaled) - n_future + 1):
    X_train.append(training_set_scaled[i - n_past:i, 0:dataset_train.shape[1] -1 ])
    y_train.append(training_set_scaled[i + n_future -1 :i + n_future, 0])

X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)

print('X_train shape == {}.'.format(X_train.shape))
print('y_train shape == {}.'.format(y_train.shape))
```

---

```
from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.Sequential()


model.add(keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_past, dataset_train.shape[1]-1))))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))

model.add(keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.LSTM(units=32, return_sequences=False)))
[enter image description here][1]
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation = 'linear'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
```

---

```
%%time
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=1e-10, patience=2, verbose=1)
rlr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.5, patience=2, verbose=1)
mcp = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='weights.h5', monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True)

tb = TensorBoard('logs')

validation_split=0.2, verbose=1, batch_size=256)
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, shuffle=True, epochs=3, callbacks=[es, rlr, mcp, tb], validation_split=0.2, verbose=1, batch_size=1000)
```

Comment: Does it raise any warning or error message? What is the problem?

Comment: I don't see any problem with the code, if you are not happy with the accuracy, try to increase the data and change some hyperparameters like decreasing the learning rate, decreasing the batch size and change the optimizer to see any improvement with the accuracy.